# Annotate sum of vote scores to an item in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a situation, need to count sum of vote scores and annotate that to an item queryset.

model:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(
        Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="votes")
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="votes")
    score = models.IntegerField()
```

I tried different variations of this but keep failing:

```
all_votes = Vote.objects.filter(item=OuterRef('pk'))
Item.objects.annotate(total_score=Sum(Subquery(all_votes.values("score"))))
```

I get this back all the time:

```
ProgrammingError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a  subquery here. You can annotate with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Item.objects.annotate(
    total_score=Sum('votes__score')
)
```